# auto backup usb batch

Tags: batch-file, usb, backup

I tried to write this

```
 if exist "H:back-me-up.txt" xcopy H:\*.* %UserProfile%\desktop\backup\*.* /y/e
pause
```

to make a backup from a usb when it is plugged in the computer using task scheduler.
   I wanted to delete the pause so i won't have to press a key after every run but when i do that  the program just starts and stops at every 2 seconds and sometimes it does that even though i have written the pause back.
  I am new to this things please do not get angry if i did everything wrong.

Comment: The destination shouldn't have the wildcards.  The destination should just be the folder path.

Comment: You have a missing backslash in your `If` statement too: `If Exist "H:\back-me-up.txt" XCopy H:\ "%UserProfile%\Desktop\backup" /E /EXCLUDE:back-me-up.txt /Y`

Comment: @Compo, the `/EXCLUDE` option expects a text file containing a list of (partial) paths to exclude... Anyway, well spotted (the `\ `)...